Как преобразовать числа в byte java?
Вот мой код.
private void sendJoystickData() {
        int a = 0xABCD;
        int b = (int) Math.floor(direction * 81.92f);
        int c = (int) Math.floor(speed * 163.84f);

        int d = a ^ b ^ c;

        Log.d("BMessage", String.valueOf(b));
        Log.d("BMessage", String.valueOf(c));

        byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
        bytes[0] = (byte) (a);
        bytes[1] = (byte) ((a >> 8));

        bytes[2] = (byte) b;
        bytes[3] = (byte) (b >> 8);

        bytes[4] = (byte) c;
        bytes[5] = (byte) (c >> 8);

        bytes[6] = (byte) d;
        bytes[7] = (byte) (d >> 8);

        Log.d("BMessage", Arrays.toString(bytes));

        // Отправляем сообщение
        MessageManager.SendMessage(bytes);
    }

Столкнулся с проблемой, что отрицательные данные некорректно переводятся. Если я беру положительное число, то всё хорошо. Однако при отрицательном он выдает странные ответы.
Если я беру число -100 и умножаю него на 163.84f, после чего округляю у меня получится -16384. При переводе на 16тиричную это 4000.
В выводе я получаю C000 = 49152.
Помогите решить проблему

Если -16384 это 4000, то 16384 это что?

А каким образом получаются двухбайтовые числа, если вопрос в заголовке о преобразовании в знаковый тип byte в диапазоне [-128..127]?

Если вы преобразуете C000 в int, то и получите 49152. А вы попробуйте преобразовать его в short.

Основная проблема в вашем коде заключается в том, что при преобразовании отрицательных чисел в байты происходит переполнение, и числа интерпретируются неверно.
Когда вы преобразуете отрицательное число в тип byte, происходит переполнение, потому что byte имеет знаковый тип и использует 8 бит для представления значений от -128 до 127. Если значение выходит за пределы этого диапазона, происходит переполнение, и число интерпретируется неверно.
Например, если у вас есть число -100 и вы преобразуете его в byte, результат будет 156, потому что -100 в дополнительном коде представляется как 156.
Попробуйте добавить побитовые операции & 0xFF. Они будут гарантировать, что только младшие 8 битов каждого числа сохраняются при преобразовании в байт. Это позволит избежать проблем с некорректным преобразованием отрицательных чисел:
private void sendJoystickData() {
    int a = 0xABCD;
    int b = (int) Math.floor(direction * 81.92f);
    int c = (int) Math.floor(speed * 163.84f);

    int d = a ^ b ^ c;

    Log.d("BMessage", String.valueOf(b));
    Log.d("BMessage", String.valueOf(c));

    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    bytes[0] = (byte) (a & 0xFF);
    bytes[1] = (byte) ((a >> 8) & 0xFF);

    bytes[2] = (byte) (b & 0xFF);
    bytes[3] = (byte) ((b >> 8) & 0xFF);

    bytes[4] = (byte) (c & 0xFF);
    bytes[5] = (byte) ((c >> 8) & 0xFF);

    bytes[6] = (byte) (d & 0xFF);
    bytes[7] = (byte) ((d >> 8) & 0xFF);

    Log.d("BMessage", Arrays.toString(bytes));

    // Отправляем сообщение
    MessageManager.SendMessage(bytes);
}


К сожалению это не помогает.

Подождите, но ведь -16384 это 0xC000, а 16384 это 0x4000. В чём у вас состоит проблема?

В конвертере показывает, что C000 это 49152. Как вы получили, что это -16384?

Давайте продолжим общение тут: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155335

@FroggerProgger если вы упоминаете какой-то конвертер, то напрашивается логичный вопрос - а этот ваш конвертер вообще умеет в отрицательные числа?

@andreymal вопрос логичный, я попробовал еще несколько конвертеров, лишь 1 показал, что С000 = -4000 в 16тиричной (-16384 в 10тичной)

Если говорим о short (он же Int16), то 0xC000 это -16384. А если о int или long (они же Int32 и Int64), то 0xC000 это 49152.

@EugeneKrivenja Окей, однако что мне делать, чтобы перевести это в пакете в нормальный вид? (Не вид C000 а вид -4000)

-4000 это некорректная запись. HEX отрицательным не бывает. Что делать я уже писал в комментарии к вопросу.
